# Calling constructor with member as argument parsed as variable definition

Tags: c++, constructor, g++, standards

I observed peculiar behavior in g++4.6.3. When creating a temporary by calling class constructor `File(arg)` the compiler chooses to ignore the existence of `arg` and parse the expression as `File arg;`

- Why is the member name ignored?
- What does the standard say?
- How to avoid it? (Without using new `{}` syntax)
- Is there a related compiler warning? (I could use an arbitrary string arg and it would still work quietly)

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

class File {
public:
    explicit File(int val) : m_val(val) { std::cout<<"As desired"<< std::endl; }
    File() : m_val(10) { std::cout<< "???"<< std::endl;}

private:
    int m_val;
};

class Test {
public:
    void RunTest1() { File(m_test_val); }
    void RunTest2() { File(this->m_test_val); }
    void RunTest3() { File(fhddfkjdh); std::cout<< "Oops undetected typo"<< std::endl; }
private:
    int m_test_val;
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    t.RunTest1();
    t.RunTest2();
    t.RunTest3();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ???
$ As desired
$ Oops undetected typo
```

Comment: You can't directly call a constructor, only when you make an object or use placement new.

Comment: How does 'fhddfkjdh' even work? This is nowhere defined and should result in a compile error?

Comment: @PoweRoy, It is treated as: `File fdfdsfsda()`

Comment: @Albert no it is not, it's treated as `File fdfdsfsda`. `File fdfdsfsda()` is a function declaration.

Comment: @chris, I don't want to call it. I want to create a temporary object using the constructor that accepts int as argument. See `Test2`

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, You're right.

Comment: @Albert so use `this->m_test_val`...

Comment: Why not just bind the temporary to a variable that immediately leaves scope again? That may feel superfluent, but is IMO far less confusing and doesn't suffer from these problems. — But good thing you brought this question up, +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler treats the line:

```
File(m_test_val);
```

as

```
File m_test_val;
```

so you're actually creating a named object called `m_test_val` using the default constructor. Same goes for `File(fhddfkjdh)`.

The solution is `File(this->m_test_val)` - this tells the compiler that you want to use the member to create create a named object. Another would be to name the object - `File x(m_test_val)`.

Comment: Another solution is to use uniform initialisation syntax: `File{m_test_val}`.

Comment: @Mankarse from the question - "Without using new {} syntax"

Comment: Why isn't `m_test_val` treated the same as `this->m_test_val`.

Comment: @Albert because you can declare local variables that hide members with the same name. It's the same as `int m_test_val`. Just how the parser works...

Comment: @Albert: Because the C++ grammar rules state that when ambiguities occur, declarations will be preferred over expressions.

Comment: @Mankarse, that's what I was looking for! Is there a way to tell the compiler to warn about such ambiguities ?

Comment: @Albert well, technically, there is no ambiguity. :) The thing is you're in this position because you have a temporary that does nothing... If you needed to use it, you wouldn't be here in the first place :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, I encountered it in a test assertion that had to check if the *correct* constructor throws an exception. I agree with you that it is a rare scenario.